# How would you translate "throttling" to Chinese?

Tags: translation

Just the word throttle or when it is used in phrases like "bandwidth throttling" or "throttle internet connection"

Comment: `throttle` -> `限制`, then `Bandwidth Throttling` -> `带宽限制`, `Throttle internet connection` -> `限制网络连接`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bandwidth throttling=带宽限制

Throttled internet connection=（带宽）受限的网络连接